# Welcome page before WordPress (sub directory install)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

1. I installed WordPress to a sub directory: `example.com/wp`
2. I use a [rewrite rule](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Using_a_pre-existing_subdirectory_install) to serve WordPress from my root URI: `example.com`

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

3. I want to provide a welcome page for project launch: `example.com/welcome.html`

It will have a simple welcoming message and should redirect to a working version of my WordPress. I do have pretty URLs enabled in WordPress. From my `welcome.html` page I can link to `example.com/about`, for example, and it will show the about page of my WordPress (as expected).

However, I cannot link to the home page of my WordPress. I use a static page for my WordPress front page (let's call it `start`). When I link to `example.com/wp`, it will issue an error 404 in my WordPress. When I link to `example.com/start`, it will redirect to my `welcome.html` page.

---

Sounds confusing? Hope you are still with me. What I actually want:

a) Users that directly access `example.com` should see the welcome page.

b) They click a link on the welcome page and get to my WordPress home.

c) When navigating within WordPress, they should not be redirected to the welcome page.

Since I want to remove the welcome page after a couple of weeks, I want to keep it as simple as possible (no new front page template for WordPress or alike).

Is there any solution to set `welcome.html` as my `DirectoryIndex` and make all other requests redirect to my WordPress installation **including** the WordPress home? My major problem is that I **cannot** access the WordPress home page right now (neither `example.com/wp`, nor `example.com/start` or `example.com/wp/start` work), unlike any other static page (`example.com/about` works fine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally ended up using this one-line plugin to disable canonical URL redirects:

```
<?php remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical'); ?>
```

Furthermore, I reconfigured the WordPress URI on the General settings panel. Now I can both, call the home page of my blog and access all sub-pages, without being redirected to an error 404.

Now I'll have my `.htaccess` do a `DirectoryIndex welcome.html`, so my visitors see the splash page first. The welcome page has a link to my `index.php` page which serves WordPress. All links within the blog work.

When my project is launched, I will simply remove the `DirectoryIndex`, delete the above plugin code and reset my General settings.