# upload php file to me frontpage WORDPRESS

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create my own index.php file and make wordpress call this page first allways,there is a way to do that?

I want to keep all the wordpress template and sites just want to call a new front page (php file) created by me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lengthy explantion on [how to create a static front page for WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page).

Comment: I recently had the exact same requirement. [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594315/welcome-page-before-wordpress-sub-directory-install).